# Separation of Concerns in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have read that Xaml provides SoC in WPF, WinPhone, Win8 apps by separating GUI with Code. Then why do we need frameworks like MVVM that again separate UI with Business logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML *enables* SoC.  You still need a set of coding design patterns (like mvvm) to actually to advantage of this possibility.  There is nothing stopping you from writing horribly coupled and unmaintainable WPF apps but using an MVVM library will steer you in the right direction